# Toolbar null when restore from background

Tags: android, background-process, toolbar

So I recently updated this app to API 21, and consequentially I changed all my ActionBar to Toolbar. 
I include the toolbar into the fragment layout using  tag, and I set it up in onResume() method. All is working fine when I launch the app, and when I put it in background and immediately restore it (or in a couple of minutes), but if I let it in background for a little, and maybe use some other app, when I restore it, I've a crash. The crash happen in the second line of the setupToolbar() method, surely because the toolbar object is null. My problem is to understand why this object is null, because when I restore the app, the execution flow have to execute onCreateView() first, and then onResume (and so setupToolbar). So the toolbar have to be inflated in the layout.

This is my toolbar layout that's included in fragment_home:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/actionbar_menu"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:id="@+id/ivActionbarOpenDrawer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/back_icon"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:id="@+id/ivActionbarBack"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/rlActionbarNotificationNumContainer"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_notifies_white"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tvActionbarNotificationIndicator"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/app_red"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/tv_actionBarText"
        android:text="home"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/ivSearchIconActionbar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivActionbarNewMsgMessages"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/new_message_icon_messages"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivActionbarSettingsProfile"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_settings_profile"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is setupToolbar method:

```
private void setupToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarHome);
    ImageView ivSearch = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.ivSearchIconActionbar);
    ImageView ivMenu = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.ivActionbarOpenDrawer);
    ivSearch.setOnClickListener(onSearchClick);
    ivMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).openOrCloseDrawer();
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT: Here the stacktrace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twentyLines.app/com.twentyLines.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.twentyLines.app.controller.HomeController.setupToolbar(HomeController.java:231)
        at com.twentyLines.app.controller.HomeController.onActivityCreated(HomeController.java:123)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1794)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:967)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
        at 

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1917)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:544)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1225)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5076)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Not able to figure it out, any help will be really valued! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that your fragment is attached to the activity at this point? Sometimes the OS will create new instance of a fragment.

Comment: I'm not sure at all, no. And it sounds like a thing that could really be.. In that case, what's the right thing to do to get it attached to activity?

Comment: The FragmentPagerAdapter/FragmentStatePagerAdapter will automatically create new instances and restore the state in them. Try keeping an if check if your method and execute the code only if the fragment is attached to the activity and see what happens.

Comment: I'll try and let you know, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I added the if status to check if the fragment is attached, and it is. I also moved the method invokation in onActivityCreated(), just to be sure that is added. Still get null pointer in the second line, the null object is the toolbar. But no way to understand why.. I've added the stacktrace to the question.